# NestJS - Injected service is undefined in the constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

As per [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/components), I inject a service in a controller's constructor, but it turns out as `undefined`.

**processScraped.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProcessScrapedService } from "./processScraped.service"

console.log(`\nController - ProcessScrapedService = `, ProcessScrapedService) // logs : class ProcessScrapedService { ......

@Controller('processScraped')
export class ProcessScrapedController {

    constructor(private readonly pss: ProcessScrapedService) {
        console.log(`constructor - pss = `, pss) // logs : undefined (Should not !)
        console.log(`constructor - this.pss = `, this.pss) // logs : undefined (Should not !)
    }

    @Post()
    async processScraped(@Body() body) {
        console.log(`processScraped - this.pss = `,this.pss) // logs : undefined (Should not !)
        return this.pss.processScraped(body) // TypeError: Cannot read property 'processScraped' of undefined
    }
}
```

So :

- The service exists
- It's imported and logged correctly as a service after import
- When I inject it in my controller, it's undefined.

Maybe the problem is in the service definition?

**processScraped.service.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@nestjs/common';

@Component()
export class ProcessScrapedService {
    async processScraped(body) {
        // Some logic here
        return
    }
}
```

... Or maybe in the module?

**processScraped.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { ProcessScrapedController } from './processScraped.controller';
import { ProcessScrapedService } from './processScraped.service';

console.log(`\Module - nProcessScrapedService = `, ProcessScrapedService) // logs : class ProcessScrapedService { ......

@Module({
    controllers: [ProcessScrapedController],
    components: [ProcessScrapedService],
})
export class ProcessScrapedModule { }
```

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong here??

**EDIT** - here are my dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^4.5.9",
    "@nestjs/core": "^4.5.10",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^4.5.8",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^3.0.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^4.5.5",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^4.5.8",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.0.9",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "elasticsearch": "^14.2.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.16",
    "mongoose-elasticsearch-xp": "^5.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.0"
  }
```

and my tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [ 
            "dom",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "outDir": "../../dist/server",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Could you share your `tsconfig` file?

Comment: @KamilMyśliwiec Alright, I have updated my question with my dependencies and tsconfig

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` is missing in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Oh wow O_o I have no idea what this is, but it fixed the problem. I would never have found that by myself. Thanks Kamil, you're the man.

Comment: had the same (similar) issue today, had to add the following to my tsconfig.json   "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true

Comment: You saved my day, weird it's not included in the default `nest new project` template

Comment: Because of an issue with Jest test coverage in Angular, I did a global remove of emitDecoratorMetadata since Angular no longer needs it. Which also removed from nest which does still need the flag.

Answer (score 48):

Just stumbled across the same issue in one of my providers - the problem was that I forgot to annotate the provider with an `@Injectable()` decorator after I have added it to the respective module.

Comment: You save me hours. Thank you!

Comment: Haha, I love when this happens. It's like a checklist with possible adjacent problems. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You just saved me from spinning my wheels for hours.

Answer (score 9):

One of my providers was scoped with `REQUEST` scope. I removed it and it resolved more errors than one.

Comment: This should be upvoted higher

Comment: Also had an issue using `@Inject(REQUEST)` on a provider constructor elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 4):

Recently faced the same issue in a service that depends on a service in another module. While everything in the answers above is already in place, annotating the imported service with Inject(ImportedService) at the constructor solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you'll need to scope your request, but doing so might result in crashing tests. Make sure you override the scope in your tests, using the `Reflect` trick:

```
    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      'scope:options',
      { scope: Scope.DEFAULT },
      YourService,
    );
```