# Dependencies not being injected on NestJS with Serverless and AWS

Tags: serverless-framework, nestjs, aws-serverless

Everyone,

I'm trying to setup my first NestJS application. It is backed by Serverless on AWS.

I created a simple Controller that has a Service as a dependency. When I hit the endpoint with my HTTP Client, the object that should contain the Service instance is `undefined`. I'm not able to make it work. Could you help?

*handler.ts*

```
import { Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './src/module';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as serverless from 'aws-serverless-express';
import * as express from 'express';
import {DB} from './src/libs/db';

let cachedServer: Server;

function bootstrapServer(): Promise<Server> {
  const expressApp = express();
  const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
  return NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter)
    .then(app => app.enableCors())
    .then(app => app.init())
    .then(() => DB.connect())
    .then(() => serverless.createServer(expressApp));
}

export const handle: Handler = (event: any, context: Context) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    bootstrapServer().then(server => {
      cachedServer = server;
      return serverless.proxy(server, event, context);
    });
  } else {
    return serverless.proxy(cachedServer, event, context);
  }
};
```

*module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventController } from './event.controller';
import { EventService } from './event.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [EventController],
  providers: [EventService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*event.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

interface Event{}

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  create(event: Event) {
    return {
      id: Date.now()
    }
  }
}
```

*event.controller.ts*

```
import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EventService } from './event.service';

interface Event { }

@Controller('event')
export class EventController {
  constructor(private readonly eventService: EventService) { }

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() req)

{
    this.eventService.create(req);
  }
}
```

So `this.eventService` is always `undefined`. What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Everything seems ok to me at the first glance, what about your tsconfig ? Could your share it ?

Comment: Are you sure, that you really need Nest.js inside AWS Lambda? It increase your "cold starts". Potentially your users/front-end will wait time-to-time to 10 seconds for response from Lambda.

Comment: Hi Victor I am trying to setup my nestjs project with AWS lambda, I am unable to get any specific documentation regarding the integration of nestjs with AWS, could you give me some information or any particular documentation you followed? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing a line from tsconfig add this below:

"emitDecoratorMetadata": true

Credits to the God of Nestjs Mr. Kamil's reply:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121886/6301493