# Tsyringe returns undefined instance of a service in controller

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, tsyringe

I am having trouble using tsyringe DI with controller, service and repository

I have three classes: UserController, UserService and UserRepository.
For service and repository, I am using interface for DI (IUserService and IUserRepository)
the DI for repository "inside" service is working fine. But the controller can access the service only in constructor. When I try to access de userService in another method, I getting a userService undefined

The Controller

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { RequestResult } from '../../contracts/requestHandle/request-result'
import {inject, injectable } from 'tsyringe'
import { UserDto } from '../../contracts/transfer-objects/user-dto'
import { UserLoginDto } from '../../contracts/transfer-objects/user-login-dto'
import IUserService from '../../contracts/interfaces/services/user-service-interface'

@injectable()
export class UserController {
    constructor(
        @inject("UserService")
        private userService?: IUserService 
    ){
        this.userService!.getUserById('1').then((teste) => {
            console.log("teste", teste)
        })
    }

    async getUserById(request: Request, response: Response<RequestResult<UserDto | null>>){
        try{
            console.log("serverInstance", this.userService)
            const entity = await this.userService!.getUserById(request.params.id)
            return response.status(200).json(entity)
        }catch(err){
            const result = new RequestResult<any>(null, true, "Erro ao buscar o usuário")
            return response.status(500).json(result)
        }
    }
}
```

The Service

```
import { inject, injectable, Lifecycle, scoped } from "tsyringe"
import { UserModel } from "../contracts/entities/user-model"
import { UserDto } from "../contracts/transfer-objects/user-dto"
import { sign } from "jsonwebtoken"
import { RequestResult } from "../contracts/requestHandle/request-result"
import automapper from "../contracts/utils/automapper"
import type IUserRepository from "../contracts/interfaces/repositories/user-repository-interface"
import IUserService from "../contracts/interfaces/services/user-service-interface"
import { UserLoginDto } from "../contracts/transfer-objects/user-login-dto"
import { RequestAnswer } from "../contracts/requestHandle/request-answer"

@injectable()
export class UserService implements IUserService {
    
    constructor(
        @inject("UserRepository")
        private userRepository: IUserRepository
    ){}

    async getUserById(userId: string) : Promise<RequestResult<UserDto | null>>{
        console.log("getUserById", userId)
        const id = parseInt(userId)
        const userModel = await this.userRepository.getUserById(id)

        if(userModel){
            const result = automapper.map("UserDto", UserDto, userModel)

            return new RequestResult<UserDto>(result) 
        }
        else{
            return new RequestResult<null>(null, false, "Usuário não encontrado.")
        }
    }
}
```

The Repository

```
import { context } from '../../repository/context/dbContext'
import { UserModel } from '../../contracts/entities/user-model'
import IUserRepository from '../../contracts/interfaces/repositories/user-repository-interface'

export class UserRepository implements IUserRepository {
    
    async getUserById(userId: number) : Promise<UserModel | null> {
        console.log("getUserById", userId)
        const user = await context.user.findFirst({ where: { id: userId } })
        return user
    }
}
```

The DI config

```
import { container } from "tsyringe"
import { UserService } from "../business/user-service"
import { UserRepository } from "../repository/repositories/user-repository"

import IUserRepository from "../contracts/interfaces/repositories/user-repository-interface"
import IUserService from "../contracts/interfaces/services/user-service-interface"
import { UserController } from "./controllers/user-controller"

container
    .registerSingleton(UserController)
    .registerSingleton<IUserRepository>("UserRepository", UserRepository)
    .registerSingleton<IUserService>("UserService", UserService)
```

As I am using the getUserById inside the controller constructor, the first query is ok. UserDto with "name: test" and other info is correct. But, the second call (with postman) for route thats call de "async getUserById" (or any another method) in controller returns "serviceInstance undefined" as you can see bellow.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/api/server.ts`
getUserById 1
getUserById 1
server running on port 3000
teste RequestResult {
  hasError: false,
  message: undefined,
  result: UserDto { name: 'Test', email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test123' }
}
serverInstance undefined
GET /user/1 500 6.019 ms - 69
```

My Question is: Why the "this.userService" is ok inside controller constructor but it is undefined in the method?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/50121886/6727154?

Comment: Yes, it´s ok in my tsconfig.ts